# Running multiple Python scripts in different directories in a sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run multiple experiments, which are in different folder. I want to save the results in the main folder. Something like this:

Main folder

- Main_run_file.py

  - Results.txt
  - Experiment_1

    - Run_file.py
  - Experiment_2

    - Run_file.py
  - Experiment_3

    - Run_file.py

I already tried with the following code:

```
import os

mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the MAIN folder
mydir_tmp = mydir + "\Experiment_1 - 40kmh" # add the first experiment folder name
mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir_tmp) # change the current working directory
mydir = os.getcwd() # set the main directory again
import Run_file

mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the MAIN folder
mydir_tmp = mydir + "/Experiment_1 - 60kmh" # add the second experiment folder name
mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir_tmp) # change the current working directory
mydir = os.getcwd() # set the main directory again
import Run_file
```

However, this only runs the first Run_file and not the second one. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: hey, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963270/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-write-output-to-txt-file/21963346 , he had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The second `import Run_file` is ignored, since python considers this module as already imported.

Either you replace those import statements by statements like this: `import Experiment_1.Run_file`, without forgetting to add the `__init__.py` files in your subdirectories,

Or you call your python scripts with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) as you would do from a command-line;

```
from subprocess import call

call(["python", "./path/to/script.py"])
```

You are also missing the point about current directories:

1. In the second `mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the MAIN folder`, `mydir` is still the previous subfolder
2. Python importing system does not care about you to change the working directory: imports are managed using the python path which depends on your python installation and the directory where you run your main script.

> More here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

try out subprocess :

```
import subprocess

with open("Results.txt", "w+") as output:
    subprocess.call(["python", "./Experiment_1/Run_file.py"], stdout=output);
    subprocess.call(["python", "./Experiment_2/Run_file.py"], stdout=output);
    ...
```

if you need to pass arguments to your `Run_file.py`, just add it as so :

```
subprocess.call(["python", "./Experiment_2/Run_file.py arg1"], stdout=output);
```